# HTML5 Email Validation regex only one domain

Tags: html

I try to valide email format with regex:

```
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9.-_]{1,}@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]{1,}[.]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}" value="{{ $user->email or null}}" autofocus required title="example@mail.com">
```

But when i put : matthew.john@mail-domain.co.uk it's working i would like to refuse this mail format
i want to accept only :

```
matthew.john@mail-domain.co
matthew.john@maildomain.co
matthew.john@mail-domain-test.co
```

`mathieu..mourareau@berger-levrault.com` is also working i would like to refuse when there is two dots ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below regex and validate at : https://regex101.com/r/fH5hJU/1

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,}\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{0,}@[a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}$
```

Comment: happy to help :)

Comment: n*i-pont.c*oulomb@be.rg*er-domain.com is working what sould be the regex to refuse this ?

Comment: @MathieuMourareau "ni-pont.coulomb@be.rg*er-domain.com" should not be working as per the regex above. you can test in the regex101 site link I shared ? the problem may be elsewhere [screenshot : https://imgur.com/xBFJ4SA ]